# jenkins time out error

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I am creating a job in Jenkins and want to use execute shell in configure job, what should I do also I am getting this error :

```
    ERROR: Timeout after 15 minutes
FATAL: Failed to fetch from git@XXXXX.git.XXXXXXXX.com:/XXXXXXXX.git
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from git@XXXXX.git.XXXXXXXX.com:/XXXXXXXX.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:623)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:855)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:880)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1254)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:624)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:530)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1732)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:234)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git.exe fetch --tags --progress git@XXXXX.git.XXXXXXXX.com:/XXXXXXXX.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code -1:
stdout: 
stderr: 
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1407)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1195)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$200(CliGitAPIImpl.java:87)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:266)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:621)
    ... 10 more
```

Comment: Are you using UNIX/Linux or Windows? What is the Git plugin version?

Answer (score 1):

This happens usually if the git host is not in the `known_hosts` and/or if the git command is waiting for a password input.